# How to write Integration Tests for MEAN application

Tags: mongodb, docker, express, continuous-integration, mean

Currently, I'm creating a project that incorporates the MEAN stack, Docker, and Travis CI. I'm using Travis CI to automate builds for unit testing, integration testing, etc. I'm using Docker to help create a test environment. I've already successfully created unit tests thanks to resources via Medium. However, I haven't found many resources on writing integration tests for a MEAN application. I want to create tests to see if I get expected values in the Angular application when it connects to the REST API endpoints from Express, and the Express application is connected to a MongoDB server. Does anyone have any resources or advice on how to write these tests, and to execute them in a Dockerized test environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having done something similar myself, just a piece of advice.

Test the services independently, like e2e tests for the api server, mail service for the frontend web app. If the selenium tests run alright with the webpage/app, and the api end point is on the local machine then everything looks to be working. There is nothing magic in docker. Your local configs should reflect what you're trying to test, and avoid overcomplicating things and write the testing yourself.

Tools often take more time to learn than the actual thing you're trying to acomplish if you do it yourself. Document it adequatly so the consumer of the container can replicate with minimal effort.

It's actually pretty hard, good luck.